# Xcode 8.3 XCtest issue with CocoaPods

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcode8, xctest, podfile

Swift xctest class would not build using `inherit! :search_paths` when referencing main target module files. Error occurred `@testable import HelloWorld` where HelloWorldClassA would be unknown ref

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'HelloWorld' do

  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for HelloWorld
  pod 'Bolts-Swift'

    target 'HelloWorldTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths

    end

end
```

Comment: FYI Xcode 8.3.3 (8E3004b) w Cocoapods 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Changed `inherit! :search_paths` to `inherit! :complete` which correctly links all main target classes (apparently).